# Find an attribute in an XML document and output children in PHP

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have included my PHP code with a snippet of the XML file I am retrieving data from.

I want to display the data from the XML file similar to how I used it as an ID. Within the ID it uses the ID as an index however I see that it won't work as a date.

My first idea was to just use xPath and leave it as this but I would like to format my data similar for consistency.

As a beginner with PHP and XML any insight or documentation that could further my studying with either the language or the format style would be appreciated.

The problem I am having is to find the index value of the relevant attribute that has been inputted and outputting it individually in a format such as the ID Search.

```
<?php
if($_GET["SearchChoice"] == "ID Search"){ #WORKING FINDS THE VALUE OF DATA NEEDED
    $xml=simplexml_load_file("XMLtest.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
    $passID = intval($_GET["IDsend"]);
    if ($passID !== 0){
        $passID = $passID - 1;
    }
    #echo $xml['date'];
    #echo var_dump((string)$xml['date']);
    $attr = $xml->finances[$passID]->attributes();
    echo "Date: ";
    echo $attr['date'];
    echo $xml->finances[$passID]->day . ",<br>Projection: ";
    echo $xml->finances[$passID]->projection . ",<br>Recommended Staff: ";
    echo $xml->finances[$passID]->recommendedStaff . ",<br>Staff Wages: ";
    echo $xml->finances[$passID]->staffWages . ",<br>Actual: ";
    echo $xml->finances[$passID]->actual . "<br>";
}
elseif($_GET["SearchChoice"] == "Date Search") { 
    $xml=simplexml_load_file("XMLtest.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
    $passDate = strval($_GET["DateSend"]);
    $nodes = $xml->xpath("/january/finances[@date='". $passDate . "']"); # Instead of xpath possiblity: loop through to find date then output it similar to ID Search?
    print_r($nodes);
}
else {
    echo "Error 1 <br>";
    echo $_GET["SearchChoice"];
}
```

Here is a portion of the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<january>
    <finances id="1" date="01-01-2016">
        <projection>414</projection>
        <recommendedStaff>20</recommendedStaff>
        <staffWages>100</staffWages>
        <actual>250</actual>
    </finances>
    <finances id="2" date="02-01-2016">
        <year>2016</year>
        <month>01</month>
        <day>02</day>
        <projection>124</projection>
        <recommendedStaff>8</recommendedStaff>
        <staffWages>150</staffWages>
        <actual>250</actual>
    </finances>
    <finances id="3" date="03-01-2016">
        <projection>687</projection>
        <recommendedStaff>20</recommendedStaff>
        <staffWages>150</staffWages>
        <actual>250</actual>
    </finances>
    <finances id="4" date="04-01-2016">
        <projection>587</projection>
        <recommendedStaff>15</recommendedStaff>
        <staffWages>150</staffWages>
        <actual>250</actual>
    </finances>
    <finances id="5" date="05-01-2016">
        <projection>124</projection>
        <recommendedStaff>5</recommendedStaff>
        <staffWages>150</staffWages>
        <actual>250</actual>
    </finances>
    <finances id="6" date="06-01-2016">
        <projection>874</projection>
        <recommendedStaff>22</recommendedStaff>
        <staffWages>150</staffWages>
        <actual>250</actual>
    </finances>
</january>
```

Comment: You have not explained what the problem is that you're trying to solve, and why the code provided doesn't work. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @miken32 Forgive me, I have clarified my post now.

Comment: There's no reason you can't use the date in exactly the same way you used the ID, you just need to make sure the date is formatted in exactly the same way because XML treats it as a string.

Comment: @Mike I didn't think this would work as I thought the ID search turned into the index value?

Comment: @Mike could you provide an example, I've used it the exact same way however the output is null.

Comment: I've never used simpleXML, just DOMDocument and DOMXPath so the nodeList would be the same regardless of whether I searched on ID or date. Does your xpath statement return any values (count($nodes) > 0)? If not, what is the exact date string you are passing to xpath?

Comment: @Mike This is what is returned: `Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [id] => 11 [date] => 11-01-2016 ) [projection] => 135 [recommendedStaff] => 10 [staffWages] => 150 [actual] => 250 ) )` The date passed is always in the 00-00-0000 format and with different strings due to it being a user input

Comment: Posted a suggestion as an answer. Hope that clears it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("XMLtest.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

switch ($_GET["SearchChoice"])
{
  case 'ID Search':
    $nodes = $xml->finances[$passID];
    break;
  case 'Date Search':
     $passDate = strval($_GET["DateSend"]);
     $nodes = $xml->xpath("/january/finances[@date='". $passDate . "']");
     if  ($nodes)
         $nodes = array_shift($nodes);   //  First match
     break;
  default:
    $nodes = NULL;
}

if  ($nodes)  //  Don't care how we got them
{
    echo $nodes->day . ",<br>Projection: ";
    //  etc
}
```

This loads the file at the start and then creates a node (stored in $nodes) based on your search choice (familiarize yourself with switch statements - very useful, especially the "break" command when it's used or not used).

After the switch statement, you have a node regardless of how you got it. That's good practice in coding - the condition is "taken care of" and from here on out is not an issue.

In actuality, it might be a better idea to just use xpath for both options - minimal difference between the different code paths makes for easier debugging and maintenance.

Comment: Could you explain what exactly this does, as stated a newbie to PHP and any XML type formatting. Therefore within the case statement it makes no sense.

Comment: Good point. I brought in some of the comments from earlier and expanded my answer to include a little explanation. It's much easier to think in code!